# How often is drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext: supposed to be called?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have a custom MKOverlayRenderer. I add an MKOverlay (also custom) to the MKMapView after the first region change (when it moves from the default location to the user's). The rendering speed was pretty laggy, so I logged the function calls.

```
2016-07-20 14:03:21.486 MyApp[360:38679] mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:
2016-07-20 14:03:22.351 MyApp[360:38679] addOverlay:level:
2016-07-20 14:03:22.353 MyApp[360:38679] mapView:rendererForOverlay:
2016-07-20 14:03:22.460 MyApp[360:38709] drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:
2016-07-20 14:03:22.460 MyApp[360:38706] drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:
2016-07-20 14:03:22.501 MyApp[360:38709] drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:
2016-07-20 14:03:22.504 MyApp[360:38706] drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:
2016-07-20 14:03:22.504 MyApp[360:38707] drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:
2016-07-20 14:03:22.560 MyApp[360:38707] drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:
2016-07-20 14:03:22.562 MyApp[360:38709] drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:
2016-07-20 14:03:22.582 MyApp[360:38713] drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:
```

This is without touching the device. Is drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext supposed to be called repeatedly like this?

Comment: @matt Are you sure this isn't typical? My app does have a small amount of code that runs in a secondary thread after an HTTP request returns, but everything GUI related is within a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ })` block.

Comment: Sure, I could be wrong. The "lag" could be somewhere else. You can use Instruments to check.

Comment: @matt Oh, you're the same guy who answered. Lol. Yeah, I think the OS is using multiple threads on it's own accord. I clipped rendering to the MKMapRect provided by the function and now it's blazing fast. I was beginning to regret the last 4-6 hours I spent learning how to customize the overlays. Now it's paying off though. Thanks man.

Comment: " I clipped rendering to the MKMapRect provided by the function and now it's blazing fast" Cool! Thanks for reporting back about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext supposed to be called repeatedly like this?

Yes. The visible map is composed of tiles. `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` is called once for each tile (as you would know if your implementation actually looked at the incoming `rect` parameter).

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Yeah, I feel dumb now. I'm usually pretty good about understanding all the parameters before I utilize an override. I'm just in a bit of a hurry on this project. I'll make sure there's not a threading issue like matt suggests in his OP comment, and then I'll give this the check mark. Thanks.